# telebot.apihelper.ApiTelegramException: A request to the Telegram API was unsuccessful. Error code: 400. Description: Bad Request: chat not found

Tags: python, database, telegram, telegram-bot

I copied this code from the docs but I'm getting the above error

```
import telebot import os

BOT_TOKEN = "My_Bot_Token"
bot=telebot.TeleBot(BOT_TOKEN)
 
@bot.message_handler(commands=['start', 'hello']) 
def send_welcome(message):
    bot.send_message(message, "Howdy, how are you doing?")
     
  
bot.infinity_polling()
```

Could someone please tell me whats wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
bot.send_message(message, "Howdy, how are you doing?")
```

for the send_message method you should pass the chat id of the message instead of the entire message object

so i assume it'd be something like,

```
bot.send_message(messsage.chat.id, "Howdy, how are you doing?")
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the following code:

```
    import telebot
    bot = telebot.TeleBot("yourtoken", parse_mode=None)
    @bot.message_handler(commands=['start'])
    def send_welcome(message):
        bot.reply_to(message, "Smt")
```